# Authentication for 'HTTPPost' action on Teams MessageCard to call API through Azure App Proxy

Tags: http-post, microsoft-teams

I have an internal API that I'm making available through Azure App Proxy with AAD Pre-authentication.
Now I want to call that API from a MessageCard HTTPPost action in Teams.
When I click on the action button I do not see any errors, and Fiddler shows me a 200 respose and I can see the token in the authorization header and the below in the body:
{"status":"Completed","actionId":"65d36e8b-e90a-4007-a556-bc4c74da8f1e","performedAt":"2019-12-03T16:23:45.0463267Z","properties":{"displayMessage":""}}
But nothing happens after that.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you test your API with [Webhook.site](https://webhook.site/) and see if you are able to get proper response.

Comment: Thanks @Subhasish, but I'm not sure how that can help. My problem is calling an API using HTTPPost in a Microsoft Teams mesage card.It works fine if call a Microsoft Flow Webhook, but not when calling an API through App Proxy.

Comment: @NizarGHRIBI, Can you please share the card JSON which we can use to repro